# Managing a four-digit ID

Tags: javascript, string

I'm creating an ID manager that generates IDs in a `0001` format, including the zeros. To do this I thought of using a String but I can't think of an efficient a way of incrementing it. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Your question is confusing. What do you mean by "iterating over it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an integer internally to generate the ids.
Format it to a string with the correct format later as a second stage of the generation process.

Working with Strings internally will introduce unnecessary complexity and problems. Strings are not meant to be used for calculations or incrementation.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a highly efficient (`O(log(n))`) [`left-pad`](https://github.com/stevemao/left-pad) module!

```
let counter = 0;
function generateId() {
  return leftPad(counter++, 4, 0);
}
```